# Javascript wont load after visual is reloaded with new data

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am creating custom style on Arcadia data (BI Tool) . I notice that after i tried to expand my table column or goes to page 2 on a table,it will revert back to its original stylesheet and my custom js will stop functioning.

For an example , i have 3 tables in a page

```
    <div>
    .. table 1 ..
    </div>
    <div>
    table 2 ..
    </div>
    <div>
    table 3 ..
    </div>
```

once page is loaded,all custom styles/js stop firing . In a scenario where table 2 consist of 10 page,  10 data loaded per page. once i click on the next page, when data is loaded , my js stop.

ive tried document.ready , preventDefault. All attempts failed to launch fire js after data is loaded.

```
f.afterDraw = function () {
 const evt = d3.selectAll("#" + arcapi.chartId() + " span.crosstab-expand")      

  evt.on("click", function(e) {
      console.log('click')
  });   

 };
```

This is an example of the code stucture,
 Is there anything i need to include in my code to force my js to fire when new data is loaded?

i realized that there was ajax called being made to call data and reload it to table. went to chrome developer mode > network > xhr and realised that there was a response.

So i am assuming that once ajax is made, all custom js disappeared

**Update**

i did tried to do

```
 $( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
       // chChange.style('background','red')
      let b = d3.selectAll("#" + arcapi.chartId() + " td.viz-td- header").append('div').attr('class','roger').text("test")
        console.log('data fired')

      });
```

when data is reloaded or ajax is completed, it does fire the log "data fired". but the div i have appended with text "test" will disappear .

Comment: Yes, if ajax etc causes some of the DOM structure to be replaced then any click handlers (or other event handlers) attached to any of the replaced nodes will disappear. Classic solution is to delegate click handling to a static container (a DOM node that is not replaced). See [.on( events [, selector ] [, data ] )](https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data).

Comment: hi @Roamer-1888 , i did `$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() { }` , when i did a log , it is firing but dom structure still wont capture what was originally developed.